# Intensity and compensator for a jump process

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

**Set-up and assumptions.** Let $(\mathscr{F}_t, t \geq 0)$ be a right-continuous complete filtration. Let $(X_t, t\geq 0 )$ be a pure jump $\mathbb{R}$-valued process with unit jumps, that is, 
$$
X_t = \sum\limits _{i = 1} ^\infty I\{ \tau _i <t \},
$$ 
where $\{\tau _i \}$ is an a.s. increasing sequence of $(\mathscr{F}_t)$-stopping times, a.s. $\lim_{i \to \infty} \tau _i = \infty$. Assume also that $E X _t < \infty$, and that all $\tau _i$ are totally inaccessible.

We know by Doob-Meyer decomposition theorem that there exists a  predictable process $(A_t)$ such that 
$$
X_t - A _t
$$
is an $(\mathscr{F}_t)$-martingale.

Assume that we also know that for some uniformly bounded predictable continuous process $(\alpha _t, t \geq 0)$ a.s.

$$
P\big[X_{t + \Delta t} - X _t = 1 \mid \mathscr{F}_t \big] = \alpha _t \Delta t + o(\Delta t), \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$
$$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
P\big[X_{t + \Delta t} - X _t = 0 \mid \mathscr{F}_t \big] = 1 - \alpha _t \Delta t + o(\Delta t), \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ 
$$
$$
P\big[X_{t + \Delta t} - X _t > 1 \mid \mathscr{F}_t \big] = o(\Delta t).
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
$$

**Question.** Can we prove that  $A_t = \int\limits _0 ^t \alpha _s ds$?

**Thoughts.** Intuitively  $\alpha _t$ should be the intensity of jumps for $(X_t)$ and $X _t - \int\limits _0 ^t \alpha _s ds$ should be a martingale. However I have not found any reference confirming this. It is proven in multiple references that the inverse implication is true, that is, if $A_t = \int\limits _0 ^t \alpha _s ds$, then (1) - (2) holds.  For example, in  [Point Processes and Queues. Martingale Dynamics](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/bimj.4710300220) (3.5) in Chapter 2 is very similar to (1)-(2). Another example is Lemma 2.22 in Chapter 2 of [Enlargement of Filtration with Finance in View](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319412542). However I did not find the answer to the posted question and I don't see how to show it myself, and would very welcome suggestions or suitable references.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming conditions (1)-(2) hold, to prove that the compensator is almost surely absolutely continuous, one needs an extension of the Ethier-Kurtz criterion.  This extension is discussed [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.3053.pdf); see (4) and Ref. [28], which I copy below.

- Y. Zeng, Compensators of Stopping Times, PhD thesis, Mathematics
  Department, Cornell University, 2006

Comment: I came across that paper too, and I see how it is possible to show that the compensator is a.s. absolutely continuous. The question still remains: even if we also know  that $(A_t)$ is a.s. absolutely continuous, can we claim that $A_t = \int _0 ^t \alpha _s ds$?

Comment: I may be missing something, but I believe that once you know that $A_t$ is absolutely continuous, with density $\beta_t$, you may use (1) and (2) to express $E[A_{t+\Delta t}-A_t|\mathscr{F}_t]$ and expand in $\Delta t$. This relates $\alpha$ to the conditional expectation of $\beta$. Thus $\alpha_t=\beta_t$ a.s. iff $\beta$ is $\mathscr{F}_t$-predictable.